# Html/CSS for image (.svg) in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, image, webview

I have been trying a number of different ways, but I just can't get it to work. I want to load a .svg file in a Android WebView. The file exist on disk and I create the html like this now:

```
    String html = "<html><body bgcolor=\"#eeeeee\">";
    for(File svg : svgs) {
        html += "<img src='file://" + svg.getPath() + "' style='background-color:white;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'/>";
    }
    html += "</body></html>";
```

It looks alright, but not as good as I want. It leaves very little space at top and it is not using the space on sides enough. I want the margin to be the same at top and on the sides, like a few percentages of the image width.

I also want it to "drop shadow".

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to get the drawable from SVG, and then you can render it in ImageView and/or WebView.

Comment: It renders fine, it is that it is not filling the WebView nor dropping a shadow that is the problem.